# Attach process to a CommandLine instance

Tags: command-line, process

I'm trying to launch an application on the commandline so I can see what it prints out for the standard output, but every time I launch it, it launches the GUI and the commandline acts has the process has ended.

I've even tried launching it from a C# code and use the method WaitForExit() but it just doesn't wait.

I know it is possible to do because my friend is able to do it and we're using the same bat to launch the application.

EDIT: I Launch it like this:

```
java -DproxySet=true -jar Minecraft.exe
```

Any tips would be appreciated, 
thanks

Comment: How are you launching the application? Can you post your code?

Comment: Sound like the application in question is not a console application but a windows application.

Comment: java -DproxySet=true -jar MyApp.jar that's how I launch it. And it is a Java application that has a GUI but like I said my friend is able to do it.

Comment: @João Silvestre: If your friend is able to do it, have you asked them how they are able to?

Comment: @Bernard He simply uses the same bat I'm using, that is what I can't figure out.

Comment: Have you tried prefixing it w/ "cmd /K"?

Comment: @Chad Retz - Tried it now and didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that one of you has `java` defaulting to `-server` and one to `-client` *and* that that distinction causes process detachment.  I can't seem to find the documentation to support that theory, but [this faq](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#compiler_default) indicates that the default could be different across Windows boxes.

So, try adding `-server` and then try replacing `-server` with `-client` and see if that works.

Also, do a `java -version` on both your and your friends computers.  This difference could account for it as well.

Comment: I appreciate the answer however, when I try with -server it says I'm missing the server version of the JVM.